# Upload image and show preview without refresh the page by using ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-ajax, image-uploading

Is there anyone who know the exact approch to perform such functionality. 
Upload image and show preview without refresh the page by using ajax  in asp.net

Comment: the same old question...What Did U Try?

Comment: i cant get the proper way to refresh the page without a post back .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-after-upload-without-page-refresh-or-postback-using-ASP.Net-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx

This should guide you through.
Thanks